# tSQLt test cases for database insert and update via stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsqlt

I want to write tSQLt test cases for database insert and update via stored procedures.

I followed the official documentation of tSQLt and installed CLR into the database.

I can see multiple tables and hundred of stored procedures are imported when I installed the tSQLt. Not sure those are really required for tSQLT tests to run.

And created the procedure

```
    USE [Speciman_Order]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [AccessionDetailsTest].[Fetch Records]    Script Date: 8/18/2019 6:51:42 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [AccessionDetailsTest].[Fetch Records]
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @TIMEINTERVAL int = 24;
        DECLARE @rowCount int;
        DECLARE @CURRENTTIME datetimeoffset = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()

        SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
            Accession
        WHERE 
            OrderStatus = 'UC' and SWITCHOFFSET(AccessionDate, DATENAME(TZ, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())) <= DATEADD(hh, -@TIMEINTERVAL, @CURRENTTIME) 
            and SWITCHOFFSET(AccessionDate, DATENAME(TZ, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())) <= @CURRENTTIME

        SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT;

        EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals 25000, @rowCount
    END;

    EXEC tSQLt.Run AccessionDetailsTest
```

When I try to run it multiple times - it throws an error saying the procedure already exists. Not sure how can find the test and class in this ocean of procedures being imported during installation.

And when I run this. I get 0 execution and every field are in 0 count.

Please help in creating the tSQLt testcase for database insert and update queries. I also read something about mocking the database instead of real time insert and update. Please assist me with understanding this concept

Answer (score 0):

Add `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE...` instead of `CREATE PROCEDURE` this will not give you the error of procedure exists already and for record count first run that select query from your procedure seperately to check records exists in that table you are looking for or not.

Comment: 'CREATE OR REPLACE' is Oracle syntax. 'CREATE OR ALTER' is available SQL Server 2016 SP1 and later.

Comment: umm yeah..you are right I went by oracle syntax, will update my answer thanks mate!

Comment: Changing alter in my procedure led to "Invalid object name 'AccessionDetailsTest.Fetch Records"

Answer (score 0):

A test is a normal stored procedure. So, all the same rules apply. For example, to change it when it exists already you need to either ALTER it, manually remove it first, or put it in the same script that creates the class, as `tSQLt.NewTestClass` deal with the removal.

There is however one important difference: to be recognized as a test, the stored procedure name needs to start with the four letters “test”.

Also, all tSQLt objects live in the tSQLt schema, so it should be easy to distinguish them from objects you created. 
And yes, I did not write all those tSQLt objects because I was bored and wanted to fill your database. They all have an important function.

Comment: Can you please help in writing small select test procedure that select 1 row of a table? so i can test remaining insert,select,update sp's.

Comment: As per your suggestion i have created the procedure and running it through tSQLt run testname. However, I can still see 0 executions and 0 errors. I altered my procedure in the question. Request you to take a look at it.